# Creating a file in node.js, using an encoding (CP437 / IBM) which is not part of the supported standard node encodings [ascii/base64/latin1/...]

Tags: node.js, encoding, fs, codepages

I am processing Files with different encoding-types.
Right now, any encoded file is transformed to utf-8 and saved to my SQL DB.

My goal ist to generate new files with the same encoding as the original data.
I am able to decode hex as CP437/IBM but unable to write the resulting String to a File maintaining the desired encoding.

`decodedString = cptable.utils.decode(437, myHexString);
fs.appendFile(filename, decodedString, [options.encoding],(err)=>{
   console.log("please help me")
}`

The result is a file with faulty encoding, but also contains a hidden message.

Comment: the [options.encoding] is in practice one of the supported node encodings:
    ascii
    base64
    hex
    ucs2/ucs-2/utf16le/utf-16le
    utf8/utf-8
    binary/latin1 (ISO8859-1, latin1 only in node 6.4.0+)

Comment: If you want to maintain the original encoding, then instead of saving the utf8 `decodedString` - save the original `myHexString`.